# How does a nerve cell adjust if O2 diffusion is interrupted?

Tags: physiology

What effects would it have on a nerve if the oxygen supply is cut off? Is there any data on this?

Does the nerve conductance velocity increase? What about the Amplitude and receptor-channels on/in the nerve?

Funnily enough it's insanely hard to come by an answer to this question, or maybe I'm just searching at the wrong places....

Comment: There should be plenty of studies on this topic. At least it is quite a well known fact that brain is one of the first organs to be affected by of oxygen deprivation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If Oxygen diffusion is interrupted, there is a serious problem. Neurons inside of the brain slowly start to die, many other things like change in personality or the inability to process pain impulses occur if the brain is deprived of oxygen.If this is not fixed within 15 minutes it is impossible to survive.

The actual effects on the neurons are as follows:
Like in most cells the first solution to this kind of circumstance is anaerobic metabolism, the same happens in neurons but it does not last long and it is inefficient. As far as i'm concerned nerve conductance decreases in this kind of scenario and the receptors shrivel.

Well if the receptors are shriveling, they shouldn't be able to transfer impulses meaning that nerve conductance should stop.

This link to an article on the effects on the brain from oxygen deprivation.
https://www.livestrong.com/article/106179-effects-lack-oxygen-brain/

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was also thinking, I'm gonna leave the question open for a bit longer, maybe somebody can add more information, hope you don't mind.

Comment: Brian, it would be great if you can add some references to support your answer and explain a bit on how lack of oxygen affects the conductance. (Hint: ATP synthesis, Na/K pumps, Neurotransmitter release/re-uptake).

Comment: @WYSIWYG please elaborate, all I can find are general impacts on the whole human, not a single cell lol

Comment: @schokakola then I can write a new answer myself. I need some time for it. Brian is almost there. But there needs to be better referencing.

Comment: @brian please try to cite more authoritative references like peer-reviewed articles or books. Blogs are just slightly more than opinions. They are not rigourous and can miss important details. You need to find articles on effects of hypoxia on neurons which is not a very difficult to search topic. Also, you haven't taken my hint on the effects of loss of ATP on different neurological processes.

Comment: Ok I will try to find some better references and talk bout ATP synthesis.

Comment: By the end of tomorrow I will try to complete my explanation.

Comment: Also thanks for the feedback on my answer

Comment: lol thanks , also i don't care about citations, i just want to know whats true

Comment: @schokakola it does not matter whether you care or not. Citing proper references is essential as per the site policy. Answer are not supposed to be just for the satisfaction of one user; it should be useful to anyone who wants to know about the particular topic.